# Toolbar title disappearing when changing orientation in collapsed state

Tags: android, toolbar

I am trying to create a collapsible toolbar like the one on [chesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) repository, but I am facing this problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THdxcyEc1CA&feature=youtu.be

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want toolbar always expanded, else the same state(opened/closed) from portrait to landscape?

Comment: That would be desirable, yes, so the same state you were in but with the title properly positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the state of AppBarLayout on configuration change(orientation), store it. Then you can set that state for the AppBarLayout after configuration change applied.

```
public class CheeseDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "cheese_name";
AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
boolean isCollapsed = false;

//state change listener
AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener toolbarStateListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            // Collapsed
            isCollapsed = true;
        } else {
            // Not collapsed
            isCollapsed = false;

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String cheeseName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(cheeseName);

    //getting app bar layout
    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    //set listener to listen state change of app bar layout
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(toolbarStateListener);

    loadBackdrop();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //save state on orientation change
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isCollapsed", isCollapsed);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //get state on orientation change
    isCollapsed = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isCollapsed");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //set state of app bar layout
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(isCollapsed);
}

private void loadBackdrop() {
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    Glide.with(this).load(Cheeses.getRandomCheeseDrawable()).centerCrop().into(imageView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I have edited CheeseDetailActivity in CheeseSquare repository.

Comment: this is not working, what I want is the toolbar to stay in the same state (which is already happening in the default behavior) but with the title always in the correct position. If you check the video you can see that after rotating the device the title is gone.

Comment: Did you check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184950. This issue was closed. You can use new version of  support library to avoid this condition. I'm using support library version 25.0.1. In this it is working perfctly.

Comment: you are right, it does not happen with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

On the onConfigurationChanged you could try to run

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
     @Overrride
     public void run(){
         toolbar.invalidate();
     }
},[Try different time lapses(miliseconds)]);
```

Comment: But that would be noticeable wouldnt it?

Comment: have you tried it?, maybe is so fast it isnt noticeable. i know is pretty hacky but i have no clue how to solve this xD